# Django Context contains not defined field when using RequestContext

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Hi I'm writing a django project, and I write template code like this:

```
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/user/">Users</a></li>
                {% if user %}
                    <li><a href="/user/{{ user.id }}/">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/logout/">Log Out</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="/login/">Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/signup/">Sign Up</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
```

Now in login view I write like this:

```
def login(request):
    if user_logged_in(request):
        return redirect('/')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = LogInForm()
        return render_to_response(LOGIN_PATH, {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But when I run the server, no user is logged in, and visit login page, it shows Settings and Log Out(there is a user object in context), but it shouldn't!

If I remove RequestContext, say return render_to_response(LOGIN_PATH, {'form':form}), it will be OK. And

```
return render_to_response(LOGIN_PATH, {'form':form, 'user':None}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

is OK too. But I don't want to do it.

I know it's dirty design, well... I'm looking for suggestions and solutions. Many thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

your tag just checks for a user object, not for an authenticated one.

check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) for more informations on what you can do with an auth user :)

Answer (score 0):

The default setting for `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` includes `"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"`. This context processor adds a `user` to cotnext, which will be anonymous if the user is not provided in request so.

If you want to be able to know whether or not the user is authenticated in template the @Samuele Mattiuzzo answer is what you should use, but if you don't want, for any reason, to include the user in context, then you need to modify the default TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting without the auth context processor.

For more information [read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) or [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/context_processors.py).